# How do I use a SpEL expression on the aggregator.aggregation option of the Spring Cloud Stream Aggregator Processor?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have three separate message payloads:

```
"id": "1234"

"type": "space-crite"

"attributes": {
  "ferocity": 10,
  "appetite": 10,
  "cuddliness": 0
}
```

I would like to use the Spring Cloud Stream aggregator-app-starter processor to combine these three message payloads into one:

```
"id": "1234",
"type": "space-crite",
"attributes": {
  "ferocity": 10,
  "appetite": 10,
  "cuddliness": 0
}
```

by using the aggregator processor's aggregator.aggregation option. The documentation says a valid value for this property is a SpEL expression for aggregation strategy and by default it generates a collection of payloads. One of the integration tests for the aggregator processor uses this expression:

```
#this.?[payload == 'foo'].![payload]
```

to generate an aggregated message of "foo" from separate payloads of "foo" and "bar".
While the tests have been very helpful, the documentation doesn't provide very many examples on how to use SpEL expressions in the context of Spring Cloud Stream Starter Apps, which is a shame, because I know I'm missing out on a very powerful feature.

Using an expression that looks like this:

```
 #this
```

as the value for the aggregator.aggregation property creates a payload that is a collection of GenericMessage objects each with their own payload and header properties. I'm hoping to create a GenericMessage with a size of 1 that has a payload property that contains the 3 incoming messages.

Can someone point me to some examples of how to use a SpEL expression with this processor option? Is what I'm attempting possible?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the payloads are strings...

Try `get(0).payload + get(1).payload + get(2).payload`.

If you want newlines between the payloads, use

```
T(String).format(get(0).payload + '%n' + get(1).payload + '%n' + get(2).payload)
```

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, the `#root` object of the aggregation is a `Collection<Message<?>>` not a `List<Message<?>>` so the above won't work.

You can replace each element with `new java.util.ArrayList(#root).get(0).payload` etc, but that's rather ugly (and inefficient since you create a new list to grab each element). I'll see if I can come up with a better solution.

**EDIT2**

Perhaps this will get close to what you want...

```
#root.![payload].toString()
```

Testing:

```
MessageGroup g = new SimpleMessageGroup("foo");
g.add(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
g.add(new GenericMessage<>("bar"));
Collection<Message<?>> messages = g.getMessages();
Expression e = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(
        "#root.![payload].toString()");
System.out.println(e.getValue(messages));
```

produces

```
[foo, bar]
```

To remove the braces:

```
#root.![payload].toString().replaceAll('[\[\]]', '')
```

(as long as your JSON doesn't have `[]` in it, which is the case in your example).

Comment: Updated my second edit to remove the unneeded `ArrayList`.